# Set CPU usage or manipulate other system resource in C

Tags: c, resources, cpu-usage

I have specific application to make in C. Is there any possibility to programmatically set CPU usage for process? I want to set CPU usage to eg. 20% by specific (mine) process for few seconds and then back to regular usage. while(1) take 100% CPU so its not bes idea for me. Any other ideas to manipulate some system resources and functions that can provide it? I already did memory allocation manipulations but i need other ideas about manipulating system resources.
Thanks!

Comment: That might be useful : http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33059/draw-with-your-cpu

Comment: Consuming 20% of CPU power is a requirement for your application?

Comment: @rakib - something like that, and i dont know how to achieve that

Comment: @user2973468 - If you are using Linux then perhaps you can use `taskset` to affine a task to a particular CPU. For example - if you have 4 CPU and you affine a task to 1 CPU, then you are using 25% of total CPU power. The other alternative might be using - cgroups.

Answer (score 0):

What I know is that you may be able to control your application's priority depending on the operating system.

Also, a function equivalent to `Sleep()` reduces CPU load as it causes your application to relinquish CPU cycles to other running programs.

Comment: Sleep() causes the OS to schedule another process, so your process' CPU usage gets reduces, but not the overall system CPU usage. I think you can't control overall CPU usage from your program.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to answer a question that became more and more complicated once you dug into it?

What you do depends upon what are you trying to accomplish. Do you want to utilize "20% by specific (mine) process for few seconds and then back to regular usage"? Or do you want to utilize 20% of all the CPU usage of the entire processor? Over what interval do you want to use 20%? Averaged over 5 sec? 500 msec? 10 msec?

20% of **your** process is pretty easy as long as you don't need to do any real work and want 20% of the average over a reasonably long interval, say 1 sec.

```
for( i=0; i=INTERVAL_CNT; i++ )    //untested syntax error ridden code
{
  for( j=0; j=INTERVAL_CNT*(PERCENT/100); j++ )
  {
    //some work the compiler won't optimize away
  }
  sleep( INTERVAL_CNT*(1-(PERCENT/100)) );
}
```

Adjusting this for doing real work is more difficult. Note the comment about the compiler doing optimization. Optimizing compilers are pretty smart and will identify and remove code that does nothing useful. For example, if you use myVar++, declare it local to a certain scope, and never use it, the compiler will remove it to make your app run faster.

If you want a more continuous load (read that as a load of 20% at any sampling point vs a square wave with a certain duty cycle), it's going to be complicated. You might be able to do this with some experimentation by launching CPU consuming multiple threads. Having multiple threads with offset duty cycles should give you a smoother load.

20% of the entire processor is even more complicated since you need to account for multiple factors such as other processes executing, process priority, and multiple CPUs in the processor. I'm not going to get into any detail, but you might be able to do this using simultaneously executing multiple heavy weight processes with offset duty cycles along with a master thread sampling the processor load and dynamically adjusting the heavy weight processes through a set of shared variables.

Let me know if you want me to confuse the matter even further.